# no pg_hba.conf for host

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I get following error when I try to connect using Beekeeper-Studio :

```
no pg_hba.conf entry for host "105.104.156.80", use"sdgij;sdhfhhuih", database"uhoidfgiosdff", no encryption
```

Here is my pg_hba.conf file:

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5
```

Comment: Why is this tagged with [tag:heroku]? On Heroku you can't change (or even see) the `pg_hba.conf` file.

Answer (score 1):

Your database server is only accepting connections from local clients:

```
host all all 127.0.0.1/32 md5
```

You need to add a line to `pg_hba.conf` that allows connections from your local network, something like so:

```
host all all 105.104.156.0/24 md5
```

But you should be **VERY** cautious with making changes to `pg_hba.conf` as you can let in hackers on your server if not careful. See the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) for details. In particular, you should reduce the allowed address range, the database to connect to and possibly the list of allowed users.